# How to define a new theme and override the alert dialog style in framework

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I want to define a new theme in my app, and override the default Holo AlertDialog style. But there's no way I can change the background or layout of my dialogs.
I followed partly the advice of [this blog post](http://joerg-richter.fuyosoft.com/?p=181).

These are the themes:

```
<style name="CD1.Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <!-- AlertDialog attributes -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CD1.Theme.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CD1.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogCenterButtons">false</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogIcon">@drawable/cd1_ic_dialog_alert_holo</item>
</style>
<style name="CD1.Theme.Dialog.Alert" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CD1.DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

These are the styles:

```
<style name="CD1.AlertDialog" parent="android:style/AlertDialog.Holo">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/cd1_dialog_full_holo</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/cd1_dialog_top_holo</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/cd1_dialog_middle_holo</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/cd1_dialog_bottom_holo</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/cd1_dialog_full_holo</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@drawable/cd1_dialog_top_holo</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/cd1_dialog_middle_holo</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/cd1_dialog_bottom_holo</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/cd1_dialog_bottom_holo</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/cd1_dialog_middle_holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/cd1_alert_dialog</item>
</style>
<style name="CD1.DialogWindowTitle" parent="android:style/DialogWindowTitle.Holo">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

It doesn't work. The default Holo layout is still displayed. What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Move `<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CD1.AlertDialog</item>` from `CD1.Theme` to `CD1.Theme.Dialog.Alert`:

```
<style name="CD1.Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <!-- AlertDialog attributes -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CD1.Theme.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogCenterButtons">false</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogIcon">@drawable/cd1_ic_dialog_alert_holo</item>
</style>

<style name="CD1.Theme.Dialog.Alert" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CD1.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CD1.DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

**By the way:**

`android:layout` attribute requires API **11**.

If you are developing against SDK which is below 11 your can consider this project:
https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro